# jquery hover problem

Tags: jquery

My page is [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/f6gw7/).

Two problems.
1. When I do mouseover and mouseout, it will be doing the animation several times. (same as mouseover() and mouseout()). How can I do the animition immediately. When I mouseover it will appear, when I mouseout it will disappear, no more repeat. Also, it seems good with a little lag with this. I tried setTimeout but failed. It was successfully appear late but still repeat.

2.How can I make the triangle div "arrow" in center. It is in center on my laptop. But it isn't fit other screen size. How to modify it to fit all kinds of screen.

Many thanks!

Comment: +1 thanks for providing an example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here, nice and easy

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/UzMwE/)

- Center the arrow: ok, the arrow is at left:50%, but it's width is actually 60px! : 30px border * 2. So we have to position it `margin-left` -30px. **DONE!**
- jQuery: the dest element handler is an ID element (in this case `#ffloatmenu` !) that contains both `.dynamicmenu` classes. Doing so we prevent from recalling the same action hovering the same class but on another element! And we have to dequeue any animation too!  **DONE!**

`

```
$("#ffloatmenu").hover(function(){
        $("#ffloatmenu").animate({top:'0px'},{queue:false, duration:1000});   
    },function(){
       $("#ffloatmenu").animate({top:'-120px'},{queue:false, duration:1000});
})
```

`

Comment: Brilliant！ It's nice now. thanks for the sample and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `stop()`:

```
$('.dynamicmenu').hover(
    function(){
        $('#ffloatmenu').stop().animate(
            {top: 0},
            {duration: 1000});
    },
    function(){
        $('#ffloatmenu').stop().animate(
            {top: -120},
            {duration: 1000});
    });
```

[Updated JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/f6gw7/1/).

---

Your original code *seems* flawed, since the `mouseleave` function was inside of the first, the `mouseenter`, function; which might be why it behaved a little oddly. And also why using `stop()`, without changing anything else (my first attempt at a solution), didn't work.

References:

- [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).
- [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Answer (score 0):

1 - Use hoverIntent (http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) For your issue with the hover.

Answer (score 0):

For part 1 of your question, it's bouncing up & down because you're repeatedly triggering the animation.

You have the hover bound to the class called `dynamicmenu` and you have that class applied to both the arrow and the pink div.

Hovering over the arrow triggers the mouse-enter animation but the arrow moves away from the mouse which triggers the mouse-leave animation.  Immediately, then the pink `floatmenu` div slides under the mouse which simultaneously triggers the mouse-enter animation.  Without moving your mouse away, the animations continue to queue up and repeat endlessly.  When you move your mouse away, the animation queue eventually empties itself.